# Zend Framework 2 Stable Versions and Doctrine Dev Versions - Composer Configuration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

I try to get a stable version of the newly released Zend Framework 2 (2.0.2) which will track stable versions via composer.

Example here would be when 2.0.3 is released then composer update would auto update.

The issue is I am attempting to use the DoctrineModule from modules.zendframework.com and this requires the minimum-stability setting to be set to 'dev'.  When I do this the Zend Framework version then changes to 2.0.3dev which is not what I want.

Do any of you fellows know a way to have dev and stable mixed up together in the same composer configuration?

What I would like to happen is that zendframework/zendframework tracks only the stable branch and composer update returns the latest stable (in this case 2.0.2) rather than a dev version.

Here is my composer.json:

```
    {
      "minimum-stability":"dev",
      "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
      "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
      "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
      "keywords": [
      "framework",
      "zf2"
      ],
      "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
      "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",  
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
      }
    }
```

**Working composer.json using @hakre solution**

Because Doctrine pulls in other dependancies via composer the minimum-stability has to be set to 'dev'.  Setting the zendframework require to @stable resolves the issue with development versions being download.

```
      "minimum-stability":"dev",
      "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*@stable",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",  
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master"
       }
```

Many thanks for answering!

Comment: Dear Sir, into which concrete problem do you run actually? It's not clear from your question, I'd say you could be a little bit more straight forward.

Comment: Using minimum-stability changes the expected version of zend framework 2 from 2.0.2 to 2.0.3dev which is not a stable version.  What I want to do is get the latest stable version of ZF2 when doing composer update.

Comment: `"minimum-stability":"dev"` - well I'd say you should use *stable* here instead of *dev*. At least for ZF2.

Comment: Any ideas on how I do that?  I went through the docs and this is marked as a root level option so can only be set once in the configuration.  I tried using require-dev for the doctrine bits but that resulted in doctrine not being downloaded as all...

Comment: `require-dev` is for checking out a development version (e.g. when you bugfix a library to push it back upstream), look into `require` instead. I added an answer.

Comment: Quick update.  Using minimum-stability: stable doesn't work as Doctrine has dependancies that can't be resolved.  So I had to use minimum-stability:dev and set an @stable tag on the end of the zendframework/zendframework:2.*@stable definition.

Comment: Good hint, I alreay suspected something like that. It might be useful to suggest stability inheritance for required packages as a feature request to have this more straight forward and to not trick other packages into dev that you prefer stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the manual ([from <kbd>minimum-stability</kbd>](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)):

> All versions of each package are checked for stability, and those that are less stable than the <kbd>minimum-stability</kbd> setting will be ignored when resolving your project dependencies. Specific changes to the stability requirements of a given package can be done in <kbd>require</kbd> or <kbd>require-dev</kbd> (see [package links](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)).

Would lead me to say, that if you set the default via <kbd>minimum-stability</kbd> to *stable* and then for the concrete package for which you need it, tag them as *beta* or *dev*:

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*@beta",
        "acme/foo": "@dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what it is for. The minimum is just your default. In your case you want *stable* but you need to make an exception to the rule for doctrine.

Comment: Yea, I was struggling to find a way around it.  Using require-dev just did not work at all, it removed the doctrine dependancies and would not download them again.  The @ tagging (must have missed that) works a treat.  Thank you.